# How can I store input type="time" to java object

Tags: java, html, object

From my html page I want to set a input type="time" value to my java object. But I am unsure what data type I should be expecting on my java object or, is there even a type for this?

This is my html input field:

```
<input style="color:black;" type="time" th:field="*{timeOut}"></input>
```

And the timeOut field plus getters and setters:

```
public static String timeOut;

    public  String getTimeOut() {
        return timeOut;
    }

    public void setTimeOut(String timeOut) {
        RentForm.timeOut = timeOut;
    }
```

Having timeOut as a string works but i want to know if there is a better datatype i can cast to?
Thanks.

Comment: your question is unclear,make it more clear

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html to store date object and use DateFormatter for parsing and formating.

Comment: So on my html page i have a HH:MM (hours and minutes) value, i want to set this value onto my java object so that it will get submitted with the form. But what data type is input type="time", in java? @SpringLearner

Comment: Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html would be worth a look. It's Java 1.8 though.

Comment: I would suggest you to make as input type=text and use a datepicker. And sent this date(String) to server.In server use simpledateformat to convert and store

Comment: @Aron_dc Using LocalTime did not work, i was not able to parse input type="time" to LocalTime.

Comment: @SpringLearner I do not want the date I know the date already. I am just looking for the time

Comment: @ShaunLavelle send back datetime to server and in server capture only the time

Comment: @Aron_dc MY QUESTION?

Comment: @ShaunLavelle Could you please expand your question a bit further to show how you try to parse some incoming data from your input field?

Comment: @Aron_dc updated my question